# why GraphQL uses POST for non mutating queries

Tags: graphql

I get that GraphQL uses POST for mutating calls.

Why does GraphQL chose to use POST even for non-mutating calls?
Is that simply due to the fact that GET doesn't provide for body or there's more?

Wouldn't use of POST this way, be violation of the spec?

Comment: graphql, in general, is a complete violation of the spec, and yes you are correct, its due to the fact you cant have a body in a GET... I would deem a valid answer to this question is, 'it's 2019'

Comment: This explains some https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v1/requests/